# Does the Voter Model converge in $L^1$?

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence, martingale

A few questions about the discrete-time voter model, described in the following way.

Let $\Lambda = \{1, \dots , L\}^d \subset \mathbb{Z}^d$, and let $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $( N_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be i.i.d random variables uniformly distributed on $\Lambda$ and the set $\mathcal{N} := \{i \in \mathbb{Z}^d : |i|=1\}$ of the 2d nearest neighbours of the origin.

Consider $(X_n)$ on $\{0,1\}^{\Lambda}$. Fix $X_0 = x \in \{0,1\}^{\Lambda}$ and for each $i\in \Lambda$,

$X_n(i) = \begin{cases} 
      X_{n -1},& I_n \neq i \\
      X_{n-1}(I_n + N_n \; \mod L), & I_n = i
   \end{cases}$

The mod L is to assure that we remain in $\Lambda$, e.g with $d=2$, if $I_n=(1,1)$ and $N_n = (-1,0)$, then $I_n + N_n \mod L = (L,1)$.

Let $M_n = \sum_{i \in \Lambda} X_n(i).$

My interpretation of the model is that $\Lambda$ is a population and the values 0 and 1 are opinions (say pro republican or pro democrats), i.e $X_n(i) = 1$ means individual $i \in \Lambda$ has opinion $1$ at time $n$, and that with time individuals may change their opinion based on the opinions of neighbouring individuals.

Now, how can it be shown that $M_n$ is a martingale wrt to the natural filtration, and that by the martingale convergence theorem $M_n \to M_\infty \; a.s.$?

Does it converge in $L^1$?

It's seems that $M_n$ is a martingale wrt to n (where we think of n as discrete time)? Is this somehow equivalent to the natural filtration question?

As for convergence of the model, I don't know how to get this by the martingale convergence theorem. I have found in literature, that convergence time is known to be quadratic.

Any help with the formal proofs/explanations of the questions above would be great, and links to good literature/papers on this model.

Comment: Have you seen or shown it to converge in another metric/topology (such as $L^2$)?

Comment: @Dave I have not. I am currently (re) reading on convergence in martingales etc, but I find this particular problem hard for some reason. It's been a while since I did anything on markov chains / martingales.

Comment: @Dave So after some reading, I have decided that $M_n$ is a martingale wrt to the natural filtration and the filtrations obtained by $I_n$ and $N_n$. For the convergence problem, if I can show that $M_n$ is uniformly integrable then this implies the result. I'm assuing this holds, but I haven't been able to satify the UI condition(s) yet.

Comment: is it uniformly integrable?